# Calculating mean of each row, ignoring 0 values in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame with 1000 rows and 10 columns.
3 of these columns are 'total_2013', 'total_2014' and 'total_2015'
I would like to create a new column, containing the average of total over these 3 years for each row, but ignoring any 0 values.

Comment: Whats the layout of your data?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/10min.html#min):

Use [DataFrame.mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) leveraging the `skipna`  attribute.

First replace `0` with `None` using:

```
columns = ['total_2013', 'total_2014', 'total_2015']
df[columns].replace(0, None)
```

Then compute the `mean`:

```
df["total"] = df[columns].mean(
                 axis=1,      # columns mean
                 skipna=True  # skip nan values
                 )
```